# In Flet How to size 2 textfields side by side as screen is resized

Tags: python-3.x, flet

In Flet Python How to size 2 textfields side by side as screen is resized

the build function is as follows

```
  def build(self):
        return ft.Column([
            self.accid,
            self.acccd,
            self.accname,
            ft.Row([self.addline1,self.addline2,], scroll=ft.ScrollMode.AUTO ,tight=True),
            self.addline3,
            self.addline4,
            self.addline5,
            self.phoneno,
            ft.Row([
            ft.ElevatedButton("Save data",color="white", bgcolor="green", on_click= lambda e:self.save_data(self.accid)),
            ft.ElevatedButton("Delete data",color="white", bgcolor="red"),]),
        ], tight=True)
```

The page looks like this
[image]

I want the address line 1 and 2 exactly 50% of width
more over if possible if the page width is less than some minimum value they should be scrolled down one above the other